# How to find the shortest path that pass through a group of Sets?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I have an algorithmic problem where I have a number of Unordered Sets of elements, and I need to find the shortest path (Ordered combination of the sets) that pass through all of those sets. There may be thousands of sets.

For example, let there be the following 4 unordered sets:
**A**=abcdefg
**B**=cd
**C**=abch
**D**=defi

The shortest path size is **11**.

One possible solution is:
**P**=**CADB**=habcgdeficd
|**P**|=**11**

Note that sets may share elements with neighboring sets in the path!
There may also be duplicated elements belonging to different sets (as in the example above: 'c' and 'd' are duplicated in **P**, by adding **B** to **CAD**).

Please advise with an algorithm to find the shortest path as described.
Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like it could be a graph theory problem. Something like the nodes are the sets and the edges are the intersections between sets. This allows you to weight the overlap. It may wind up that you would be looking for some sort of max flow/min cut-type solution.

Comment: These problems are usually expressed in terms of strings, not sets. To clarify: given a set of words $w_1, \ldots, w_n$, where no word uses a letter more than once, you want the shortest string that contains a permutation of each of the words $w_i$? I would suspect that a truly optimal algorithm is NP-complete, by analogy with the similar well-known [shortest common supersequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence_problem).

Comment: Thanks @ConnorHarris ! That is exactly what I needed.